# I insisted to my parents that I have/had to have a bedroom of my own

Tags: word-choice, past-tense

When we moved into the new (house/home ?),

> I insisted to my parents that I **have** to have a bedroom of my own.
> I insisted to my parents that I **had** to have a bedroom of my own.

Which tense is correct here? (**have to or had to**)
And which word is correct here? (**house/home**)

Comment: If you replace insisted with insist in the first, they will both be correct. Like this, the first is present tense and the second is past.

Comment: It''s probably the same thing in your language.

Comment: I just noticed you need the past, so the second fits that.

Comment: “I insisted **that** I was given my own bedroom” is what I would have said.